# Prove that $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)$, for $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z^+$. If $a\equiv b\pmod c$ then $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)$. Use this to show that there are no $ x, y $ such that $ x + y = 100 $ and $ (x, y) = 3 $.

Since $a\equiv b\pmod c$, then $a=b+ck$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. Let $d=\gcd(a,c)$, then exists $x,y\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
d&=ax+cy\\
&=(b+ck)x+cy\\
&=bx+ckx+cy\\
&=bx+c(kx+y)\\
&=bx+cz.
\end{align*}$$
This shows that $ d = \gcd(b, c) $. Is my proofcorrect? And how do I use this for the particular result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This shows only that $\gcd(b, c) \mid d$.  It doesn't show equality.  You need to separately show $d \mid b$ (you already have $d \mid c$).

Comment: Doing $ p = \gcd (b, c) $ and reasoning in the same way, I get to the other one, right? and would have equality?

Comment: Immediate consequence of the theorem (proved in the linked dupe), viz. $\, \bmod x\!:\ \color{#c00}{y} = 100\!-\!x\equiv \color{#c00}{100}\,$ so by the Theorem we conclude that $\,(x,\color{#c00}y) = (x,\color{#c00}{100})\mid 100\,$ so $\,(x,y)\neq 3\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

A slight rephrase:

Let $d$ be *any* common divisor of $a$ and $c$, then consider $b = a-ck$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$, $d$ is a divisor of the right hand side, so $d\mid b$.

i.e. All common divisors of $a$ and $c$ are also divisors of $b$, and hence are common divisors of $b$ and $c$.

Similarly, by considering $a=b+ck$, all common divisors of $b$ and $c$ are also common divisors of $a$ and $c$.

So the set of common divisors of $a$ and $c$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $b$ and $c$. The greatest elements of the two sets are also the same.